# How to restrict some apps to appear in share chooser?

Tags: android, manifest

I don't want my app to show in share chooser of certain apps because it's causing some unexpected behaviour in my app. Or in other words, I can say that I only want certain apps to show my app in their share intent chooser. Either way, my objective would be accomplished.

My manifest includes:

```xml
<intent-filter android:label="Share with my App">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Moreover, my app has some use cause due to which I've set my launchMode to `singleTask`

Example of my issue: I want only stores like Amazon, Aliexpress etc. to send share intent to myapp, while I don't want to receive any share intent from say any random notepad text, is it possible to achieve that? if yes then how?

Comment: Seems not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

`ACTION_SEND` has no notion of accepting certain apps while filtering out the others.

It works like a whitelist rather than a blacklist, which means if your app is exposed, it can be seen by all the apps not all the apps minus 1.

Comment: Can I whitelist only certain apps then? If not blacklisting?

Comment: I don't think it's possible